# SearchContextMissingException Failed to execute fetch phase [search/phase/fetch/id]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

---

**Cluser:** I am Using elasticsearch 1.3.1 with 6 nodes in different servers, which are all connected with by LAN. The bandwidth is high and the each one has 45 GB RAM in it.

**Configuration** The Heap size we allocated for the node to run is 10g. We do have the elasticsearch default configuration except the unique discoverym, cluster name, node name and we 2 zone. 3 node belongs to one zone and the other belongs to another zone.

**indices**: 15, total size of the indices is 76GB.

Now a days i am facing the `SearchContextMissingException` exception as DEBUG log. It smells like some search query has taken to much of time to fetch. but I checked with queries, there was no query to produce high amount of load to the cluster... I am wondering why this happen.

**Issue:** Due to this issue one by one all the nodes start to collect GC. and result in the OOM :(

Here is my exception. Please kindly explain me 2 things.

1. What is `SearchContextMissingException`? Why it happen?
2. How can we prevent the cluster from these type of query?

The Error:

```
[YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,039][DEBUG][action.search.type ] [es_node_01] [5031530] 
   Failed to execute fetch phase 
   org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [es_node_02][inet[/1x.x.xx.xx:9300]][search/phase/fetch/id] 
   Caused by: org.elasticsearch.search.SearchContextMissingException: No search context found for id [5031530] 
       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.findContext(SearchService.java:480) 
       at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeFetchPhase(SearchService.java:450) 
       at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchFetchByIdTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:793) 
       at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchFetchByIdTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:782) 
       at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler$RequestHandler.run(MessageChannelHandler.java:275) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) 
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) 
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, update to 1.4.2. It fixes some known resilience issues, including cascading failures like you describe.

Regardless of that, the default configuration will definitely get you in trouble. Minimum, you may need to look at setting up circuitbreakers for e.g. field data caches.

Here's a snippet lifted from our production configuration. I assume you have also configured linux filehandles limits correctly: [see here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)

```
# prevent swapping
bootstrap.mlockall: true

indices.breaker.total.limit: 70%
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 70%

# make elasticsearch work harder to migrate/allocate indices on startup (we have a lot of shards due to logstash); default was 2
cluster.routing.allocation.node_concurrent_recoveries: 8

# enable cors
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: /https?:\/\/(localhost|kibana.*\.linko\.io)(:[0-9]+)?/

index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 4096
```

Comment: Thanks Jilles, Yes i am planning to upgrade the elasticsearch 1.4.2. but i want to know what is SearchContextMissingException

Comment: The `SearchContextMissionException` is due to the invalid scroll id. while you scan the document it will return a new scroll id you need to pass the new scroll id for the next request.. Once all the documents retrieved then we have this exception.

Answer (score 0):

The same error (or debug statement) still occurs in 1.6.0, and is not a bug.

When you create a new scroll request:

```
SearchResponse scrollResponse = client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(types).setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
            .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000)).setSize(maxItemsPerScrollRequest).setQuery(ElasticSearchQueryBuilder.createMatchAllQuery()).execute().actionGet();
String scrollId = scrollResponse.getScrollId();
```

a new scroll id is created (apart from the scrollId the response is empty). To fetch the results:

```
long resultCounter = 0l; // to keep track of the number of results retrieved 
Long nResultsTotal = null; // total number of items we will be expecting
do {
    final SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollId).setScroll(new TimeValue(600000)).execute().actionGet();
    // handle result
    if(nResultsTotal==null) // if not initialized 
        nResultsTotal = response.getHits().getTotalHits(); //set total number of Documents
    resultCounter += response.getHits().getHits().length; //keep track of the items retrieved
} while (resultCounter < nResultsTotal);
```

This approach works regardless of the number of shards you have. Another option is to add a break statement when:

```
boolean breakIf = response.getHits().getHits().length < (nShards * maxItemsPerScrollRequest);
```

The number of items to be returned is `maxItemsPerScrollRequest` (per shard!), so we'd expect the number of items requested multiplied by the number of shards. But when we have multiple shards, and one of those is out of documents, whereas others do not, then the former method will still give us all available documents. The latter will stop prematurely - I expect (haven't tried!)

Another way to stop seeing this exception (since it is 'only' `DEBUG`), is to open the `logging.yml` file in the `config` directory of ElasticSearch, then change:

```
action: DEBUG
```

to

```
action: INFO
```